# Why do we use sine with trigonometric substitutions?

Tags: calculus

We use $x=asinx$ substitutions in integrals like i shown below. What I want to ask here is, why we use sine instead of cosine here? What would happen if i substitute with cosine instead of sine? Is there any particular reason here?

$ \int f(x)dx = \int \sqrt{ a^2 - x^2}dx $

Comment: Not really. Go try it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I get a $\sqrt{a^2(1-cos^2(x))}$ from trying and then it makes me to reach a solution like $a.sinx$ from $\sqrt{a.sin^2(x)}$